# No idea how to write complex SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group, subquery

I have following db structure:

File, User, FileRevision (has foreign key to File, and many-2-many connection through intermediate table to User).

I want to fetch all FileRevision-s that:

1. are newest/freshest in their corresponding File-s,
2. have many-2-many link to User that performs search (permission checking).

I found out that I can do (1) by executing something like:

```
SELECT created_on, file_id FROM FileRevision
WHERE created_on = (SELECT MAX(created_on) FROM FileRevision
                    WHERE filed_id = file_id)
```

but I have no clue how to simultaneously perform also m2m permission check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of the "greatest-n-per-group" problem.  Here's how I solve it with no subquery and no `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT f1.*
FROM Permissions p -- this is the many-to-many table
JOIN FileRevision f1
  ON (f1.file_id = p.file_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN FileRevision f2 
  ON (f2.file_id = p.file_id AND f1.created_on < f2.created_on)
WHERE p.user_id = ? AND f2.file_id IS NULL;
```

Substitute the desired user id for the "`?`".

Comment: This answer is my favourite + JOIN sequence seems to me to be the powerful weapon for complex lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your query:

```
UNION
SELECT created_on, file_id
FROM FileRevision fr
WHERE fr.user_id = ?
```

Replace ? with whatever value you want based on your permission checking.

Additionally, if you replace your query to:

```
SELECT created_on, file_id 
FROM FileRevision fr 
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT file_id, MAX(created_on) as latestDate 
    FROM FileRevision 
    GROUP BY file_id
  ) latest ON latest.file_id = fr.file_id 
           AND latest.latestDate = fr.created_on
```

You'll avoid the correlated (repeating) subquery.

Comment: Thank you, I went mostly with Bill Karwin's solution but this also showed me some new SQL tricks.

Answer (score 1):

To check permsissions you need to check that a record exists in ther other many-2-many permissions table for the user requesting the files.  So add an And/OR Exists clause...
If you want (as I suspect) only the last revision that the requestor has access to, use AND.

If you want Both the last Rev and the records the the requestor has access to, use OR.

```
SELECT created_on, file_id 
FROM FileRevision r
WHERE created_on = 
    (SELECT MAX(created_on) 
     FROM FileRevision                    
     WHERE file_id = r.file_id)
  And Exists       --  Change 'And' to 'Or if you want both
     (Select * From M2MIntermediatePermissionsTable
      Where File_Id = r.File_Id
          And userId = ?)
```

Comment: Thank you, Exists + intermediate table select is very useful!